# 'HADOOP_COMMON_HOME' error while installing hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I am installing hadoop (3.2.2) on Ubuntu 18.04 on VMFusion for the first time. At the end of the installation when I run 'hdfs namenode -format' it shows: `ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_COMMON_HOME`.

This is what I have on .bashrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=PATH:JAVA_HOME/bin:HADOOP_HOME/bin:HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_OPTS="HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"
```

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you reference a variable you need to prefix with a `$`, i.e.:

```sh
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
```

Comment: Thank you Ben. This helps me get past this step. However I am now stuck at './start-dfs.sh'. It says 'no such file or directory', although I can see the files are there. Do you have any idea about this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error ("ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_COMMON_HOME") but because of different reasons. I had written well all the environment variables but inside the file hadoop-functions.sh, which is executed when using start-dfs.sh for example, it didn't detect the environment variable HADOOP_COMMON_HOME no matter how i tried to fix it.
The solution I found was to hardcode these paths (it wasnt only hadoop_common_home who failed but also others hadoop variables) inside the file hadoop-functions.sh. I created all these variables just before the first error I got (line 251):

```
HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
HADOOP_YARN_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
if [[ ! -d "${HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}" ]]; then
    echo "${HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}"
    hadoop_error "ERROR: Invalid HADOOP_COMMON_HOME"
    exit 1
fi
```

This fixed my installation so I hope it's useful for anybody too.